# C array reinitialising

Tags: c

I know how to initialise an array of characters (strings) in C, let's say array called Word. I need to save different string into the array every time and I do not want the previous data to be shown. Is there anyway I can reinitialise the array? like I put "char Word[100];"

Comment: An array of `char` is not a string!

Comment: take the tour of Stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/tour so you can understand more about how this website works.

Comment: Showing the code of what you already did helps.

Answer (score 0):

To set all of the values of an array to a given value use [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

```
memset(Word, 0, sizeof(Word));
```

From the link:

> **void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);**
>
> The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area
>   pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

Comment: but let's say the first time i wrote an array into my array has length 10 and the next array has length 7. Will there be any problem with the overwriting part? also I've heard that memset can cost too much if i am iterating many times ( which I am doing).

Comment: The short answer is **no**. (cost is a relative term -- when programming on an Amiga, yes it's a concern, by the time of the 286, it was not much of a concern) If you are concerned about the cost of `memset`, test it. I'd wager, you can probably call it more than 100,000,000 in a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array like this:

```
char Word[100];
```

This doesn't actually initialize it.  The contents of the array at this point is undefined.  If you want the array to have some known contents, such as all NUL bytes, you can use `memset`:

```
memset(Word, 0, sizeof(Word));
```

You can do this any time you want to clear out the array.  Or, you can just overwrite the current content with new contents.

Comment: but let's say the first time i wrote an array into my array has length 10 and the next array has length 7. Will there be any problem with the overwriting part? also I've heard that memset can cost too much if i am iterating many times ( which I am doing).

Comment: No, there's no problem with overwriting.  As long as you know how many elements are currently in the array (or in the case of a string, it's NUL terminated), there's no problem.

Comment: so when i overwrite my new string to the word and add the null byte then it kind of doesn't care what is after the null byte. is that right?

Comment: Correct.  Any string manipulation functions know to stop at the NUL byte.

Answer (score 0):

various methods:

```
memset(Word, 0, 100); //before putting new values
```

OR

```
{ // whenever this block is entered, you get a fresh copy of 'Word'
 char Word[100] = {'\0'};
 ...
}
```

Comment: `char Word[100] = {0};` is fine... If you like the additional keystrokes, that's fine too. The null character `'\0'` and `0` are equivalent.

Comment: so using the 2nd method, the size of my array will remain 100 but has nothing in it except a null byte?

Comment: Using either method the size remains the same, it is just initialized with null-characters (all 100 of them). The same applies to `memset` as well. If you just want to set the string `Word` to an empty string, then just set the first char to `0`. (i.e. `*Word = 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your comments, I thought it would be helpful to put the efficiencies of the various methods to a quick 10,000,000 repetition test so you could see the efficiencies involved. When you talk about `memset` being costly, 'costly' is a very relative term.

While you can worry about it being more or less efficient in setting all elements of a 100 char array (or string if it contains a null-terminated series of characters), unless you are repeating the task billions of time, it is in the noise. For purposes of setting all elements to `0`, you don't care if it is a string or an array of chars. (it will be an array of 100 `0`'s or an 'empty-string' after each reset either way)

Let's look at a comparison:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {

    char word[100] = {0};
    char noword[100] = {0};
    char *p = word;
    double t1 = 0.0, t2 = 0.0;
    unsigned tests = 10000000;

    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n word : %s\n", word);

    /* let's make word an 'empty-string' */
    *word = 0;
    printf ("\n word : %s\n", word);

    /* is the data really gone - of course not - what's left? */
    printf ("\n p + 1: %s\n", p + 1);

    /* how can we really wipe it all out? */
    memcpy (word, noword, sizeof word);
    printf ("\n p + 1: %s\n", p + 1);

    /* let's try again */
    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n word : %s\n", word);
    printf (" p + 1: %s\n", p + 1);

    /* using memset */
    memset (word, 0, sizeof word);
    printf ("\n word : %s\n", word);
    printf (" p + 1: %s\n", p + 1);

    /* one more time with a loop? */
    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n word : %s\n", word);
    while (*p) *p++ = 0;
    printf (" word : %s\n", word);

    /* what about efficiency, which is more efficient?
       memcpy? */
    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n %u memcpy operations on word : ", tests);
    t1 = clock();
    while (tests--) memcpy (word, noword, sizeof word);
    t2 = clock();
    printf ("%lf (sec)\n", (t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    /* memset? */
    tests = 10000000;
    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n %u memset operations on word : ", tests);
    t1 = clock();
    while (tests--) memset (word, 0, sizeof word);
    t2 = clock();
    printf ("%lf (sec)\n", (t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    /* loop? */
    tests = 10000000;
    strcpy (word, "The string we will reset in severl ways.");
    printf ("\n %u pointer operations on word: ", tests);
    t1 = clock();
    while (tests--) {
        p = word;
        while (*p) *p++ = 0;
    }
    t2 = clock();
    printf ("%lf (sec)\n", (t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

The first series of operations show the effect on the use of `word` as a sting. Whether you simply set the first character to `0` by simple assignment with `*word = 0;`, or set all characters to `0` with `memcpy` or `memset`, the result is the same. The string is an **empty-string**.

In the case of simply setting the first char to `0`, all the other characters are still present in the array, they simply are not be considered part of the **string** `word` as a string ends at the first `null-terminating` character encountered (here the first character of the array after assignment)

**Output - Effect on String**

```
$ ./bin/str_reset

 word : The string we will reset in severl ways.

 word :

 p + 1: he string we will reset in severl ways.

 p + 1:

 word : The string we will reset in severl ways.
 p + 1: he string we will reset in severl ways.

 word :
 p + 1:

 word : The string we will reset in severl ways.
 word :
```

**Output -- Efficiencies**

As to the efficiencies, of course it depends how many times you will reset the string. However, regardless which method you use, you can easily accomplish 10,000,000 resets in a fraction of a second. So for all practical purposes when you are talking about getting input or presenting output to/from a human, it just doesn't matter. But to get a feel for the relative efficiencies of the various methods when it will depend on the optimization level requested from the compiler.

For example, with default optimization (`-O0`), the times for 10,000,000 reset repetitions were:

```
 10000000 memcpy operations on word : 0.175195 (sec)

 10000000 memset operations on word : 0.170872 (sec)

 10000000 pointer operations on word: 0.058730 (sec)
```

Both `memcpy` and `memset` taking less that 2/10ths of a second for 10 million iterations.

With full optimization (`-0fast`), the times were:

```
 10000000 memcpy operations on word : 0.077134 (sec)

 10000000 memset operations on word : 0.137333 (sec)

 10000000 pointer operations on word: 0.026722 (sec)
```

So hopefully, this has shown you what the relative `costs` involved among the various methods available are. To a large extent, it's not something you have to worry about unless you are calling the various function an extremely large number of times.